# Is it wrong to ask for a raise early, if I believe my contributions have been major?

Tags: salary, raise

I have been working at my company for about 6 months. I have had a decent number of major assignments given to me, from design work to web development to mobile app development. They've all been received well.

I happened to take a look at what the competition is offering, and for my level, it seems to be somewhere like +30k for my current job. I really like my current company though, and want to work here.

I've always learned the "rule of thumb" is wait one year before asking for a raise. Is it wrong to ask this early?

Comment: Your level hasn't changed massively in 6 months. So I would question why you took the role 6 months ago if it is massively underpaid? Or did you not check at the time?

Comment: @AndrewBerry Sometimes choosing between offers or waiting for a better one is a luxury.

Comment: @rath Of course. Or it could be the OP is overstating his level based on a good 6 months? So establishing which one is the case affects a potential answer.

Comment: @AndrewBerry In some companies we're given major tasks in the early weeks. I've been in this case and I've received a rise without asking for it. It was before the end of my first year. It was not a 30k rise anyway, more like 2-3%. I'd have asked for it but maybe not this soon. I'm glad I'm given responsibilities and it helps learning things faster, but definitely that's not what is usually expected from a junior, therefore the salary has to be adapted.

Comment: I never really think about my "level", I just do stuff as it's assigned. I've been programming professionally for 4 years, though

Comment: I wouldn't say wrong, but I would say "brave", and by "brave", I mean it in the same sense when an MP uses it in Parliament. (UK)

Comment: @Crow so how do you know you are ~30k underpaid then?

Comment: @TimF that's fine, i'm just trying to work out if the OP is a mid level in a junior role, or a junior who thinks they are mid level. As depending on which one it is affects how I would answer

Comment: When I was searching for jobs, some were offering +20k what this one was, but they were in financial so I figured they just had more money to expend. My previous job was -10k but it was my first role I had for 2 years.

Comment: What percentage would 30k be as an increase? Is that in USD?

Comment: You will be hard pressed to get a 30k raise out of your current employer, even if you direct manager wants to do it.  That high of a race will need approval as it will have big impact on the departments budget.

Comment: not looking for 30k because that's absurd, something more like 5k

Answer (score 7):

Is it wrong to ask for a raise early, rather than waiting for the normal review cycle? Well, let's say it will likely be considered presumptuous.

A better answer would be to schedule a meeting with your boss, ask how you've been doing, ask what you need to do to justify a raise ... And only if you are told you already deserve it should you ask if you could get it early and ask how much.

You took the offer. It isn't their fault that you now regret not having demanded more.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not "wrong" morally.  It could potentially leave some employers feeling like you think you are entitled.  Some employers might respect your initiative and boldness.  It's just a matter of opinion at that point.  But I would expect some level of incredulousness from your boss because no one wants to give away more money, especially when they thought they had a recently-consummated deal in place.

But let me ask you this.  If you think you can get an extra 30k elsewhere, why not just ask for the raise and if you don't get it, go get one of those higher paying jobs?  Of course, it's because you mentioned that you want to stay because you like your employer.  So what dollar-value do you place on that feeling?  That's what you have to ask yourself.  Because if you are getting paid an extra 30k but hate your job, maybe it's not worth it.  Compensation comes in many forms.

Comment: "Compensation comes in many forms." - so true. Many people hate each hour they do work, ern several times what I do, and I do not envy them.